# Change UITabBarItem Tint Color on iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Custom colors in UITabBar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/675433/custom-colors-in-uitabbar)

The iPhone UITabBar generally uses a blue and gray icon scheme.  However, the iPod Touch ships with an application from Nike that has a red icon overlay, as opposed to the blue overlay.  Here's a screen shot:

[Image Link http://1.bp.blogspot.com/_iTGXYFIkfkA/SMiXRtd8HsI/AAAAAAAAKJQ/5iwA9wcZZjw/s400/ipodtouch2_2.jpg](http://1.bp.blogspot.com/_iTGXYFIkfkA/SMiXRtd8HsI/AAAAAAAAKJQ/5iwA9wcZZjw/s400/ipodtouch2_2.jpg)

How do I do that?  Do I use the hidden setSelectedImage method in UITabBarItem?  If so, when do I call this?

Comment: Note that your application might get rejected for this.

Comment: Actually this is not a duplicate question.  The UITabBar and UITabBarItem are separate objects.  Also, subclassing the UITabBarItem  doesn't give you even close to the same access as subclassing the UITabBar does.

Comment: SWIFT 3 update: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38164547/1736679

Answer (score 1):

There is no supported way to do that without custom drawing. Tab bar items don't even use the colors in your images, only the alpha channel. See also: [Changing Tint / Background color of UITabBar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/571028/changing-tint-background-color-of-uitabbar).