# how to change UITabbar selected color?

Tags: iphone, uitabbarcontroller

according to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1355480/preventing-a-uitabbar-from-applying-a-gradient-to-its-icon-images/1356560#1356560) 
for now, Is apple will also reject this code?

and how to implement what apple will approve?

```
@interface UITabBar (ColorExtensions)
- (void)recolorItemsWithColor:(UIColor *)color shadowColor:(UIColor *)shadowColor shadowOffset:(CGSize)shadowOffset shadowBlur:(CGFloat)shadowBlur;
@end

@interface UITabBarItem (Private)
@property(retain, nonatomic) UIImage *selectedImage;
- (void)_updateView;
@end

@implementation UITabBar (ColorExtensions)
- (void)recolorItemsWithColor:(UIColor *)color shadowColor:(UIColor *)shadowColor shadowOffset:(CGSize)shadowOffset shadowBlur:(CGFloat)shadowBlur
{
        CGColorRef cgColor = [color CGColor];
        CGColorRef cgShadowColor = [shadowColor CGColor];
        for (UITabBarItem *item in [self items])
                if ([item respondsToSelector:@selector(selectedImage)] &&
                    [item respondsToSelector:@selector(setSelectedImage:)] &&
                    [item respondsToSelector:@selector(_updateView)])
                {
                        CGRect contextRect;
                        contextRect.origin.x = 0.0f;
                        contextRect.origin.y = 0.0f;
                        contextRect.size = [[item selectedImage] size];
                        // Retrieve source image and begin image context
                        UIImage *itemImage = [item image];
                        CGSize itemImageSize = [itemImage size];
                        CGPoint itemImagePosition; 
                        itemImagePosition.x = ceilf((contextRect.size.width - itemImageSize.width) / 2);
                        itemImagePosition.y = ceilf((contextRect.size.height - itemImageSize.height) / 2);
                        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(contextRect.size);
                        CGContextRef c = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
                        // Setup shadow
                        CGContextSetShadowWithColor(c, shadowOffset, shadowBlur, cgShadowColor);
                        // Setup transparency layer and clip to mask
                        CGContextBeginTransparencyLayer(c, NULL);
                        CGContextScaleCTM(c, 1.0, -1.0);
                        CGContextClipToMask(c, CGRectMake(itemImagePosition.x, -itemImagePosition.y, itemImageSize.width, -itemImageSize.height), [itemImage CGImage]);
                        // Fill and end the transparency layer
                        CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(c, cgColor);
                        contextRect.size.height = -contextRect.size.height;
                        CGContextFillRect(c, contextRect);
                        CGContextEndTransparencyLayer(c);
                        // Set selected image and end context
                        [item setSelectedImage:UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()];
                        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
                        // Update the view
                        [item _updateView];
                }
}
@end
```

Comment: Yes, Apple rejects it..
any solution??

Answer (score 5):

**Yes**, Apple *will* reject an app if you use that code.

I just had an app rejected for using private API calls. Specifically "_updateView". And I used the exact same code as above.

(If other people say that their app got approved with the same code it's just because it wasn't checked for use of private APIs.)

Comment: Yes, Apple rejects it.. any solution?? any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: If you are developing for iOS 5+ only you can use the `appearance` methods to configure the tab bar.
Before iOS 5 I usually created images for every state of the tab bar (i.e. if there are three items, I need three images: one for each selected item) and put the image on top of the entire tab bar. A search for "custom tab bar" should yield plenty of examples.

Answer (score 3):

```
[[UITabBar appearance] setSelectedImageTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
```

Comment: where do you put this? In all the view did loads of the tab bar item view controllers, or in the app delegate, or somewhere else?

Comment: this goes in the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method of the app delegate

Answer (score 0):

I suggest instead of changing color why don't you use selected tabbaritem image,
like
In iOS 6 I have change the selected tabbatitem image like -

in tabbar controller delegate method

```
- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController

{
    if([tabBarController selectedIndex] == 0)
    {
        [viewController.tabBarItem setFinishedSelectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"selected.png"]withFinishedUnselectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"unselect.png"]];
    }    
}
```

through this you can change your image.

Or you can use directly in your view controllers init(or ViewWillAppear) method, like

```
        [viewController.tabBarItem setFinishedSelectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"selected.png"]withFinishedUnselectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"unselect.png"]];
```

Answer (score 0):

## for iOS 10 (or higher):

To set selected color just set:

```
let tabBarAppearace = UITabBar.appearance()
tabBarAppearace.tintColor = UIColor.nowYouBlue
```

Above will work for all iOS version currently supported, but to change unselected color:

```
    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        tabBarAppearace.unselectedItemTintColor = UIColor.red
    } else {
        // Fallback on earlier versions
    }
```

Above code will look like this on iOS 10.

[image]