# UITabBarItem selection color

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

Is it possible to change the color of the active tab on iPhone's tab bar?
By default it is blue and it is not working with my app's color scheme.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to change UITabbar selected color?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2506290/how-to-change-uitabbar-selected-color)

Comment: Not quite... I'm looking for a legal way :)