# UITabBar selected tint color

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbaritem

I need to change uitabbar selected tint color from blue to yellow. How can i do it??? Can any one help me with this??

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to change UITabbar selected color?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2506290/how-to-change-uitabbar-selected-color)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a good starting point: [how to change UITabbar selected color?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2506290/how-to-change-uitabbar-selected-color)

Comment: It's not an end point though, for most cases (like getting your app onto the app store)