# Change font color in UITabbar

Tags: iphone, uitabbar, textcolor

How can I change the font color in a `UITabbar` on the iPhone?

In my application I am using a custom tabbar and now I want to change the color of its text.

Here is the code for my tabbar background

```
UIView *v = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
    UIImage *i = [UIImage imageNamed:@"1.png"];
    UIColor *c = [[UIColor alloc] initWithPatternImage:i];
    v.backgroundColor = c;
    [c release];
    [[self.tabBarController tabBar] insertSubview:v atIndex:0];
    [v release];
```

Comment: I think you have to subclass UITabBarController/UITabBarItem to achieve this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [changing text color of uitabbaritem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3051958/changing-text-color-of-uitabbaritem)