# How to change tabBarItem highlighted color to a color other than blue(iphone development )

Tags: iphone

I want to change the default selection of tabbaritem from blue to some other color ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot change this color unless you create your own custom tab bar.

Comment: Is there a chance of application being rejected if I use a custom color for the tabbaritem selection

Comment: If you use a custom tab bar, your application will be accepted even if the highlight color is not blue. There are some apps in the appstore that have done that. However if you use some private API to change the color of the native tab bar, then it will be rejected.

Comment: i am now using a private API method now which i got from this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1355480/preventing-a-uitabbar-from-applying-a-gradient-to-its-icon-images/1356560#1356560 ... can anyone suggest an alternative