# iphone - tabbar set imagetintcolor (offstate)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, tabbar

I see that there is `[tabBar setSelectedImageTintColor:[UIColor]]` which is great, but how do I set the imagetintcolor for the offstate?  I can't seem to find a `[tabBar setImageTintColor]` or `[tabBar setUnSelectedImageTintColor]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the "Managing the Finished and Selected Image" task's section of the docs of [UITabBarItem](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/ipad/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITabBarItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: That doesn't address the issue of coloring of the image.

Comment: The docs of `selectedImageTintColor` clearly says: `If you want to also customize the unselected image appearance, you must sent setFinishedSelectedImage:withFinishedUnselectedImage: to individual tab bar items.`

Comment: PERFECT!  This also had the bonus of helping me remove that nasty default gradient that appearred on the icons!

Comment: NOTE: "Deprecated in iOS 7.0. Use image and selectedImage with UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal instead."

Answer (score 1):

And for a quick cut 'n paste:

```
NSArray *tabBarImages = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"tab_a.png",
                         @"tab_b.png",
                         @"tab_c.png",
                         @"tab_d.png",
                         @"tab_e.png",
                         nil];


for (uint i=0;i<[_tabBarController.tabBar.items count];i++)
{
    UITabBarItem *uitbi = [_tabBarController.tabBar.items objectAtIndex:i];

    NSString *imageRef = [tabBarImages objectAtIndex:i];
    [uitbi setFinishedSelectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:imageRef] withFinishedUnselectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:imageRef]];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

For changing the look and feel of the buttons to that level of detail, you are going to have to implement your own custom UITabBar.  Here's a good reference:

http://idevrecipes.com/2010/12/16/raised-center-tab-bar-button/

Comment: that only changes the background color of the tab bar and not the tabbar images.