# UITabBarItem selectedImageTintColor. How to find the color to set as tintcolor

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitabbaritem, tintcolor

I was using the `selectedImageTintColor` property in my `TabBarController` to change the color of the selected `TabBarItem`.

The problem is that the color you set as `tintcolor` is not the final color applied, before it is changed (it gets some kind of gradient)

My question is, is it possible to find the color to apply as `tintcolor` to obtain a final color you know?

For example, I want my selected item to have a final color of

```
[UIColor colorWithRed:(154.0/255.0) green:(213.0/255.0) blue:(0.0) alpha:(1.0)
```

What are the color RGBs I should set to the property `selectedImageTintColor`?

Comment: If I understand you probably you want to prevent the gradient. Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1355480/preventing-a-uitabbar-from-applying-a-gradient-to-its-icon-images

Comment: You did, but I rather prefer to "counter" the gradient if possible

Answer (score 0):

As already stated by Ankit, your best bet is to use

```
- (void)setFinishedSelectedImage:(UIImage *)selectedImage withFinishedUnselectedImage:(UIImage *)unselectedImage
```

However, I appreciate you need to have a UIImage to be able to do this. If your designer can't provide you with this, what you can do is to draw your own UIImage in code as such.

```
- (UIImage *)imageWithColor:(UIColor *)color {
    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [color CGColor]);
    CGContextFillRect(context, rect);

    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return image;
}
```

Obviously this code doesn't draw you a gradient, but it shows you the basics of drawing a UIImage. I'd have a look at a tutorial like the following to work out how to draw the exact gradient you want:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/2033/core-graphics-101-lines-rectangles-and-gradients

Answer (score -1):

iOS does not provide an api for modifying the tint color gradient.  However apple documentation suggests to use setFinishedSelectedImage:withFinishedUnSelectedImage: method.

see more in UITabBarItem reference