# How to change tab bar item text color

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ios7

[image]

How can I change the color of "More.." text in tabbar to match with its icon color.  (Right now Performance is selected in the tab bar)

I tried to set TitleTextAttributes.

```
[moreItem setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaLTStd-Roman" size:10.0f], NSFontAttributeName,  [UIColor yellowColor],NSForegroundColorAttributeName , nil]
```

But it the text color is always set to yellow. even when the item is selected. Like this
[image]

I am trying set to white when selected and when unselected it should match with icon color. 
Thanks..
Any suggestions will be really helpful.

Comment: instead of changing text, why cant you use images? have a look [here](http://idevrecipes.com/2010/12/16/raised-center-tab-bar-button/) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6546756/2239920)

Comment: I found a better way to change it with using images for my text. Please look at my answer. Let me know if I am doing it wrong.

Comment: well, if you are satisfied, go ahead.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I found the answer for my own question.

We can set `perforamceItem setTitleTextAttributes:` for  two different states.

- `forState:UIControlStateNormal`
- `forState:UIControlStateHighlighted`

I added the following code

```
 [performanceItem setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaLTStd-Roman" size:10.0f], NSFontAttributeName,  [UIColor yellowColor], NSForegroundColorAttributeName,nil] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[performanceItem setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaLTStd-Roman" size:10.0f], NSFontAttributeName,  [UIColor whiteColor], NSForegroundColorAttributeName,nil] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
```

I need to replace the yellow color with the color of my ICONS. This is how they are looking now.

### When More is selected

[image: When More is selected]

### When Performance is Selected

[image: When Performance is Selected]

Comment: Not works on iOS 7. Look at my answer below! http://stackoverflow.com/a/23671597/1698467

Answer (score 53):

The accepted answer's code not work for me.

Here is code, that works:

```
    [[UITabBarItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:@{ NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor yellowColor] }
                                             forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [[UITabBarItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:@{ NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor whiteColor] }
                                             forState:UIControlStateSelected];
```

Answer (score 11):

**Swift 5.1** + **iOS 12.4 & iOS 13**:

```
/// Subclass of `UITabBarController` that is used to set certain text colors for tab bar items.
class TabBarController: UITabBarController {

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        if let items = tabBar.items {
            // Setting the title text color of all tab bar items:
            for item in items {
                item.setTitleTextAttributes([.foregroundColor: UIColor.black], for: .selected)
                item.setTitleTextAttributes([.foregroundColor: UIColor.lightGray], for: .normal)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Code free way to do this:

If you are just using iOS 10 then you may change the Image Tint in your Tab Bar

[image]

If you are also supporting iOS 9 and lower, then you must also add tintColor to your user definer runtime attributes in each tab bar item

[image]

if you also wish to change your icon color make sure the correct color image is in your assest folder and change Render as to Original Image

[image]

Comment: BEAUTIFUL answer.

Comment: Thank you @Adeel :)

Comment: I think beauty should be admired in it’s every form.

Answer (score 6):

This is the swift version :-

```
        for item in self.mainTabBar.items! {

          let unselectedItem: NSDictionary = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.whiteColor()]
          let selectedItem: NSDictionary = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.whiteColor()]
          item.setTitleTextAttributes(unselectedItem as? [String : AnyObject], forState: .Normal)
          item.setTitleTextAttributes(selectedItem as? [String : AnyObject], forState: .Selected)

        }
```

Or you can simply change in Appdelegate :-

```
 func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    UITabBarItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.blueColor()], forState: .Selected)
    UITabBarItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.blackColor()], forState: .Normal)
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    return true
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Swift 4:

```
UITabBarItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor : UIColor.white], for: .normal)
UITabBarItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor : UIColor.red], for: .selected)
```

Answer (score 2):

For a swift solution, let type inference be your friend:

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
  for item in self.tabBar.items! {
    let unselectedItem = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.blackColor()]
    let selectedItem = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.whiteColor()]

    item.setTitleTextAttributes(unselectedItem, forState: .Normal)
    item.setTitleTextAttributes(selectedItem, forState: .Selected)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Swift version of @skywinder answer :

```
UITabBarItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSForegroundColorAttributeName:UIColor.whiteColor()], forState: .Normal)
UITabBarItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSForegroundColorAttributeName:UIColor.whiteColor()], forState: .Selected)
```

Answer (score 2):

Nowadays if your app supports version of iOS less than 13, you should set this colours different ways:

```
if #available(iOS 13, *) {
    let appearance = UITabBarAppearance()
    appearance.stackedLayoutAppearance.selected.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: .red]
    tabBar.standardAppearance = appearance
} else {
    UITabBarItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes(UIColor.red, for: UIControl.State.selected)
}
```

In code example I set red text color for selected states of UITabBarItem, you may also need to change text color for normal state.

Answer (score 1):

This is easy , simply subclass UITabBarItem and assign it to be the class of your tab bar item in either storyboard or code. The below works perfectly for me.

```
import UIKit

class PPTabBarItem: UITabBarItem {
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        commonInit()
    }
    override init() {
        super.init()
        commonInit()
    }

    func commonInit() {
        self.setTitleTextAttributes([NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFontOfSize(13), NSForegroundColorAttributeName:UIColor.blackColor()], forState: UIControlState.Normal)

        self.setTitleTextAttributes([NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFontOfSize(13), NSForegroundColorAttributeName:UIColor.yellowColor()], forState: UIControlState.Selected)
    }
}
```

skywinder's solution is good but it triggers global scope.

Answer (score 0):

This works correctly..

```
 [[UITabBarItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                                        [UIColor redColor], NSForegroundColorAttributeName,
                                                       nil] forState:UIControlStateSelected];

    [[UITabBarItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                                       [UIColor blackColor], NSForegroundColorAttributeName,
                                                       nil] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Answer (score 0):

You could set the ***tintcolor*** and ***unselectedItemTintColor*** of **UITabBar** to change it's appearance.

```
self.tabBar.tintColor = // Your colour
self.tabBar.unselectedItemTintColor = // Your unselected item colour
```

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me on Swift 5.

In AppDelegate :

```
 UITabBarItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor : UIColor.red], for: .selected)
```