# How to change text to custom font and use custom colour in iOS 7

Tags: objective-c, ios7, uitabbar

[How to change the unselected tabbaritem color in iOS7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19662017/how-to-change-the-unselected-tabbaritem-color-in-ios7)
This does not work.

I'm trying this

```
[[UITabBarItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont fontWithName:[ThemeManager customFont] size:10.0f],
                                                    NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor greenColor]
                                                    } forState:UIControlStateSelected];
```

Colour changes but not the custom font I'm using.

Comment: I've recently been looking into the same thing. In the end I decided it wasn't possible :(

Comment: I've also run into the same problem. This is my first venture in iOS development and so far its like a magic school bus ride through Steve Jobs' small intestine.

Comment: In iOS development you will find the easy stuff is difficult and the difficult stuff is easy.

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution.

```
[[UITabBarItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont fontWithName:[ThemeManager customFont] size:17.0f],
                                                    NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor greenColor]}
                                         forState:UIControlStateSelected];

[[UITabBarItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont fontWithName:[ThemeManager customFont] size:17.0f],
                                                    NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor blackColor]}
                                         forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: Does it stay that way if you select an item and then select something else? When I found something that works it seemed to only work until the selection was changed.

Comment: Yes it stays that way

Comment: Hmm... it doesn't quite work as I would have liked though. The image in the tab bar item still uses the default tint colour.

Comment: I haven't played around with tintColour yet. If I do and I manage to get it working then il post the solution.