# Is there a way to use a custom selected image for UITabBarItem?

Tags: iphone, uitabbar, uitabbaritem

I like to have a custom selected image when a user selects an item on the tab bar, by default it selects as blue like but would like to have a green color instead. something like below any thoughts?

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just found my solution. Basically, I subclassed UITabItem and set this in the navigation controller:

```
-(void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    CustomTabBarItem *tabItem = [[CustomTabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Events" image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tabIcon.png"] tag:0];
    tabItem.customHighlightedImage=[UIImage imageNamed:@"tabIconSelected.png"];
    self.tabBarItem = tabItem;
    [tabItem release];
    tabItem=nil;            
}
```

Here's what the CustomTabBarItem class looks like:

```
@interface CustomTabBarItem : UITabBarItem
{
    UIImage  *customHighlightedImage;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) UIImage *customHighlightedImage;

@end
```

implementation:

```
#import "CustomTabBarItem.h

@implementation CustomTabBarItem

@synthesize customHighlightedImage;

- (void)dealloc {
    [customHighlightedImage release];
    customHighlightedImage=nil;
    [super dealloc];
}

-(UIImage *)selectedImage {
    return self.customHighlightedImage;
}

@end
```

Comment: what is customHighlightedImage? What did you put in the CustomTabBarItem class?

Comment: just added more details on what CustomTabBarItem looks like

Comment: I don't see `- (UIImage *)selectedImage` Anywhere in the docs for UITabBarItem. Seems to work though, so I'm gonna guess this is "Private API" and therefore fatal to 99% of projects.

Comment: what would be the method for the unselected image please?

Answer (score 6):

In iOS 6 I have change the selected tabbatitem image like -

in tabbar controller delegate method

```
- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController

{
    if([tabBarController selectedIndex] == 0)
    {
        [viewController.tabBarItem setFinishedSelectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"selected.png"]withFinishedUnselectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"unselect.png"]];
    }    
}
```

through this you can change your image.

Or you can use directly in your view controllers init(or ViewWillAppear) method, like

```
        [viewController.tabBarItem setFinishedSelectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"selected.png"]withFinishedUnselectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"unselect.png"]];
```

i hope this'll help you.

Comment: This works great, except the selected image isn't set until the tab is selected (for me the first tab is still tinted blue initially). Iterating through self.viewControllers in viewDidLoad in my UITabBarController did the trick though.

Comment: I am also facing same issue as Dustin. Please let me know how can we show selected or unselected image without selecting tab manually.

Comment: I ma not sure but you can try this line of code. :- [tabBar setSelectedItem:[tabBar.items objectAtIndex:0]];

Answer (score 2):

This is not officially supported in the SDK.  You may be able to probe and adjust the tab's views at runtime, but you risk a rejection from Apple.

Edit: For completeness, I should mention that your other option is to roll your own UITabBar.

Answer (score 2):

Just add some custom views (using insertSubview:atIndex:) when the UITabBarController-delegate-methods are called.

Example:

```
– (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {
    [tabBarController.tabBar insertSubview:someView atIndex:someIndex];
}
```

You can try changing `someIndex` yourself till you have the result you want.

Comment: this is good because it's easy to implement and it doesn't use any private method, therefore will have no problems on app review.

Answer (score 1):

For iOS5 and upwards, you can just do this:

```
rootTabBarController.tabBar.selectedImageTintColor = [UIColor greenColor];
```

Comment: That set tint color of all image. I want only one tabbar. How would I do so?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can now do this with :

```
[[[[self tabBar] items] objectAtIndex:0] setFinishedSelectedImage:nil withFinishedUnselectedImage:nil];
```

Comment: `setFinishedSelectedImage:withFinishedUnselectedImage:` is a method of `UITabBarItem`, not `UITabBar`.

Answer (score 1):

When using storyboards you can simply select your TabBarController's TabBar and then change the Image Tint in the Identity Inspector. This should also work with XIBs.

[Look here for an image describing the todos](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jrof3.png)

Answer (score 0):

In AppDelegate.m

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions (NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

[[UITabBar appearance] setSelectedImageTintColor:[UIColor redColor]]; 

return YES;

}
```

This will give you a red color, change the color with the one you wish whiteColor, blueColor etc..

Answer (score 0):

In my UITabBarController's `viewDidLoad:`, based on Rizzu's answer:

```
for (int i = 0; i < [self.viewControllers count]; i++)
{
    UIViewController* viewController = [self.viewControllers objectAtIndex:i];

    if(i == 0)
    {
        [viewController.tabBarItem setFinishedSelectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"btn_list_all_hover.png"]withFinishedUnselectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"btn_list_all.png"]];
    }
    else if(i == 1)
    {
        [viewController.tabBarItem setFinishedSelectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"btn_settings_hover.png"]withFinishedUnselectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"btn_settings.png"]];
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Dustin. My image on UITabBarItem is not set until I manually select required UITabBarItem. If you solved this problem, then give me some hint for this. If possible then please provide me code.