# CustomTabBarController not responding to delegate callbacks

Tags: iphone, ios, delegates, callback, tabbarcontroller

I have created a custom `UITabBarController` by using Martin's [tutorial](http://www.martinhoeller.net/2011/05/07/custom-tab-bars/).
My subclass `FSTabBarController` switches between view controllers, and acts normal as far as I can see.

The issue is, when I change my tabBarContoller to my subclass, It won't respond to my delegate;

```
- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
```

If I change it back to `UITabBarController` -when I use the default `UITabBarController`- the delegates works as it should.

The custom subclass uses the below function to represent tab selection:

```
- (void)_buttonClicked:(id)sender
{
    self.selectedIndex = [sender tag];
    [self _updateTabImage];
}
```

**Edit:**

AppDelegate.h

```
...
@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate,UITabBarControllerDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
@property (strong, nonatomic) FSTabBarController *tabBarController;
```

AppDelegate.m

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
...
    self.tabBarController = [[FSTabBarController alloc] init];
    self.tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:peopleViewController,viewController,profileViewController, nil];
    self.tabBarController.delegate = self;
...
}

- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
   // not called when FSTabBarController, called when UITabBarController !!
}
```

Comment: Where are you setting up the delegate?

Comment: at the application delegate, within didFinishLaunching, just after I initialize my tabBarController...

Comment: Can you also add that code please?

Comment: I have added the code you requested...

Comment: Silly question, but did you synthesize the tabBarController, to assign setters/getters as you are accessing it through them ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, downloaded the sample from his site and tested.
Yes you need to manually call the deleage from the subclass:

this is how you should change the buttonClicked function:

```
- (void)_buttonClicked:(id)sender
{
    self.selectedIndex = [sender tag];
    if (self.delegate) {
        [self.delegate tabBarController:self didSelectViewController:self.selectedViewController];
    }
    [self _updateTabImage];
}
```

Comment: thanks alot... This means I need to track down all other delegates I want to implement and call them myself within my subclass... discarding all views of UITabBarController doesn't seems to be a good way to make custom one after all...

Comment: It is because of the way the custom class is implemented. Instead of adding the buttons as normal TabBar buttons, and relaying on the TabBarController, he is actually adding UIButtons on top. I would suggest you just subclass the tabbarcontroller in a different way, so you can benefit from the tabbarcontroller delegate methods. The way is described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3762625/312312)