# Iphone UI case Study - Satisfaction Remote

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, user-interface, ios

I'd like to know how to create UITabBarItem like those in [Remote Satisfaction](http://itunes.apple.com/app/satisfaction-remote/id305593756?mt=8) (Iphone app).

And, in your opinion, how works the upper menu navigation in this view (About, Topics, Products, People) is this a UiNavigationController?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found answer for this question at this url : http://idevrecipes.com/

Answer (score 1):

You will have to be creative and come up with your custom UI. You can, however, look into 3rd party libraries, such as [Three20](https://github.com/Three20/Three20), which would come closest to the "About, Topics, Products, People" tabs.

The table uses a custom cell.

Comment: I prefer write my Custom UI :) Work with Three20 is not what i'm looking for. How you'd build the UITabbar ?

Comment: Change the background  color / tint of the Tabbar, see this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/571028/changing-tint-background-color-of-uitabbar

Comment: This's not only a change of BG image and tint. Look at the Background of the single bar item when selected. It look like different from standard UITabBar (or i'm in wrong?) 
Thank you for your help WrigthsCS

Comment: When you change the tint of the object, the buttons and sub items will follow that tint.

Comment: The solution in your previous link override a Private Api ...this's not a good solution i think.