# How to change the UITabBar colour ?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode4

I want to change the color of `UITabBar`. I used `UITabBar` by the help of InterfaceBuilder but it doesn't provide the option to change the color of tabbar I want to change by tabBar color to Blue color can any one suggest me the best way of doing this work.

Thanks in adavance.

Comment: Duplicate question of http://stackoverflow.com/q/675433/777498 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/571028/777498

Comment: You can also have readymade sample available from iDevRecipes here https://github.com/boctor/idev-recipes.

Answer (score 0):

The `UITabBar` does not have a `backgroundColor` nor `tintColor` property. You can however use graphics to change the appearance of the `UITabBar`. Check out [iDevRecipes](http://idevrecipes.com/2011/03/08/how-does-the-instagram-iphone-app-implement-a-custom-tab-bar-notification/) tutorials on how to customize `UITabBars`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
UITabBarController *tabBarC = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];

if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:@"5.0" options:NSNumericSearch] != NSOrderedAscending) {
    tabBarC.tabBar.selectedImageTintColor = [UIColor redColor];
}
```

Remember, only with iOS5+.