# change uitabbar background color

Tags: iphone, uitabbar

I am write this code but the **warning is** show **"insertSubview" may not respond**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad]; 

    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 480, 49);

    UIView *v = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];

    UIImage *i = [UIImage imageNamed:@"GO-21-TabBarColorx49.png"];

    UIColor *c = [[UIColor alloc] initWithPatternImage:i];

    v.backgroundColor = c;

    [c release];

    [[self tabBar] addSubview:v];

    [v release];

}
```

Comment: I've always had a hard time customizing UITabBars

Comment: it is perfect dublicate question .which answer for this question also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/571028/changing-tint-background-color-of-uitabbar

Answer (score 1):

Did you try

```
[[self tabBar] insertSubview:v atIndex:0];
```

Instead of `addSubview:`

Source: [Changing Tint / Background color of UITabBar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/571028/changing-tint-background-color-of-uitabbar)