# I just want to have dofferentcolor iTems on my UITabbar How I can make my colored UITabBar

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ipad

Please help me I want to make a colored UITabBar for Each Items I need differentColor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As explained in [this post on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/571028/changing-tint-background-color-of-uitabbar), subclass UITabBarController, then override the -(void)viewDidLoad method. Here's an example:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Alternate between red and blue. Obviously this is a pretty terrible example,
    //  since the number of items shouldn't be a fixed integer. Replace this
    //  with whatever you want to do with your UITabBarItems.

    int colorIndex = 0;
    NSArray *colorArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[UIColor redColor], [UIColor blueColor], nil];
    for (int itemIndex = 0; itemIndex < 3; itemIndex++) {
        // Create a frame for a subview which will overlap over the UITabBarItem.
        CGRect frame = CGRectMake((self.tabBar.bounds.size.width/2.0)*itemIndex, 
                                  0.0, 
                                  self.tabBar.bounds.size.width/2.0, 
                                  self.tabBar.bounds.size.height);
        // Initialize a UIView using the above frame.
        UIView *v = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];

        // Cycle through the colors.
        if (++colorIndex >= [colorArray count]) {
            colorIndex = 0; // Keep colorIndex from going out of bounds.
        }

        // Set alpha to 0.5 so OP can see the view overlaps over the original UITabBarItem.
        [v setAlpha:0.5];
        [v setBackgroundColor:[colorArray objectAtIndex:colorIndex]];
        // Add subview to UITabBarController view.
        [[self tabBar] addSubview:v];
        // v is retained by the parent view, so release it.
        [v release];
    }
}
```

Also, you should know that it's good practice to search the answers here on Stack Overflow before asking a new question. You could have made a lot of progress on your own using the link above. You should also post code detailing what you've tried so far--people will be more inclined to help you if you do.

I posted my code because I am still a beginner myself and I enjoyed the challenge presented by your question. If anyone has any suggestions for my code, please comment!

Anyway, hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for The reply I will Follow whtever you have told.