# stylish Tabbar in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4

How to set different style on Iphone Tabbar .want to change my application tabbar look .

help me to write simple code with detail

Comment: explain more about the question or you can try this one too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/571028/changing-tint-background-color-of-uitabbar

Answer (score 0):

```
CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, self.view.bounds.size.width, 46);
UIView *myTabView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
[myTabView  setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.2 green:0.4 blue:0.6 alpha:0.65]];
[myTabView  setAlpha:0.5];
[[self.tabBarController tabBar] insertSubview:myTabView  atIndex:0];
[myTabView  release];

// Above code is used to change Tabbarcolor
```

Comment: UIView *myTabView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 46)]; //Use width of your device here i considered iPhone width  // Instead of First 2 Lines put the above line of code