# UITabBar not updating appearance after Load

Tags: ios, uitabbar, appearance

I am having a problem with UITabBar, seems like the call to

```
[[UITabBar appearance] setSelectedImageTintColor:barColor];
```

does nothing once the tabbar is showing, if i put the line in the ViewDidLoad (ViewWillAppear) it does work.

Any hint?

Answer (score 1):

in the Apple docs for `UITabBar` it says

"The tint color to apply to the gradient image used when creating the selected image."

Note the *creating*, meaning that it reads this property when initalising/creating the tab bar, but it can't be set after. If you wanted to dynamically you'd have to get a little bit fiddly and overlay a semi transparent `UIView` over the selected image to change the colour, but it's not really ideal... There is some examples of that *type* of thing here

[Changing Tint / Background color of UITabBar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/571028/changing-tint-background-color-of-uitabbar)