# When I change the color of UITabBar it only shows up in gray

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitabbar

I'm using the following code in 'viewDidLoad' of the various view controllers of my tabbed app.

```
    UIColor *tabBarColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:85.1 green:57.6 blue:71.4 alpha:.5];
    [[UITabBar appearance] setTintColor:tabBarColor];
```

But the image that I get, which ought to be pink, is this:

[image]

I can make it lighter or darker by changing the alpha, but never colored--only black/white/gray.

Any thoughts about how I can solve this problem?

Comment: Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/571028/changing-tint-background-color-of-uitabbar

Comment: Instead of setTintColor property try setBackgroundColor

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Under header files in .m write this line `#define RGB(r, g, b) [UIColor colorWithRed:r/255.0 green:g/255.0 blue:b/255.0 alpha:1]` now where you are setting color put this code for pink color `[[UITabBar appearance] setTintColor:RGB(255, 192, 203)];` that's all

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
   if ([tabBarController.tabBar respondsToSelector:@selector(setTintColor:)]) 
    {
        [tabBarController.tabBar setTintColor: tabBarColor];
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Colors must come with decimal point after the number: `215.0/255`. Because it's float.
If you want to be precise with floats and doubles on 32bit and 64bit systems you also should add **f** after the number: `215.0f/255`. The compiler will know it's 32bit.
Now your problem is you didn't write the divide mark: **N_OF_COLORS / TOTAL_COLORS**.

Answer (score 0):

UIColor *tabBarColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:85.1 green:57.6 blue:71.4 alpha:.5]

Colors must come with decimal point after the number: 215.0/255. Because it's float.

try this:

```
UIColor *tabBarColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(87/255.0) green:(153/255.0) blue:(165/255.0) alpha:1];


[[UITabBar appearance] setTintColor:tabBarColor];
```