# How to code different selection backgrounds for each icon for IOS

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller, xcode4.5

I'm currently designing an APP for the iphone and am searching for a way to create different selection images for each icon. I've found how to just create a single selection image for the entire UItabbar, but nothing about multiple selection images. Example when you click on "news" i want the bg blue, for "announcements" red, and so on. Is this possible

Comment: Maybe you can provide some mock ups? It is hard to understand what you are trying to do...

Comment: I'm not able to post images, I don't have a 10 reputation. may be I can explain a little clearer. I'm wanting to have different "selection indicators" for each icon. So when you click "news" it goes from a grey bg to a blue bg, then when you click "ann" it goes from grey to Orange. Right now the selection indicator is blue, I was hoping to add 3 seperate ones. I mean I could just have the icons change colors, but was opening to have the whole selection change.

Comment: Here is snippet of my code    [[UITabBar appearance] setSelectionIndicatorImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tabbar_selected_blue.png"]]; I guess i'm looking for a way to set this on each separate view controller

Comment: You will probably need to do some custom drawing like described here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/571028/changing-tint-background-color-of-uitabbar, but for the UITabBarItem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following method:

```
- (void)tabBar:(UITabBar *)tabBar didSelectItem:(UITabBarItem *)item
```

That should help you identify which TabBar button was tapped by the item variable (i.e. by `item.title`) and based on that modify the TabBar's backgroundImage

To be able to use it don't forget to assign UITabBar's delegate to the view it's contained within and include `<UITabBarDelegate>` in your class header interface declaration.